# What is the Java libjli library for?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jvm-hotspot

I am using JNI to allow C code to offload some work best done in Java. [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50914575/9957820) I was trying to link the **libjvm** and **libjli** libraries for my code to work, but now I'm questioning whether I even need the **JLI** library.

I cannot find any documentation that clearly states what the purpose of the **JLI** library is.

[This other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32414536/9957820) hints at **JLI** being some OSX passthrough library:

```
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
// jli needs to be loaded on OSX because otherwise the OS tries to run the system Java
```

As does [this blog](https://nachtimwald.com/2017/06/17/calling-java-from-c/):

> When compiling on OS X it’s very important to link the jli library before the jvm library

**My questions:**

1. What is the **JLI** library for?
2. Do I need it for C/Java **JNI** development in RedHat/CentOS-only environments (no OSX)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the JLI library for?

The `libjli.so` contains a launcher interface for preparing arguments passed in the command line and launching the virtual machine with them.

The launcher [main.c](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/share/native/launcher/main.c) is the main entry point in all Java programs. It prepares the C command line arguments and passes them into `JLI_Launch` function which performs argument parsing, [loading virtual machine](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/java.base/unix/native/libjli/java_md_solinux.c#l544) from `libjvm.so`, forking primordial thread and then [passing control to the JVM](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/prims/jni.cpp#l4015).

> Do I need it for C/Java JNI development in RedHat/CentOS-only environments (no OSX)?

Very unlikely. If you need you are *probably* doing something wrong. At least I cannot imagine any useful general use-case.